# Django Sending Email: sending activation use django sendgrip

Tags: django, devops, digital-ocean, sendgrid, web-development-server

I want to send the email activation using django registration.

Below is my production settings.py

```
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'  #
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = get_secret('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply@uralholidays.com'
# EMAIL_BACKEND = "sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend"
```

The project is running fine  on my local server. but when I pushed it to the production (beta version)- it did not have any SSL.  I need the settings to work for both production (beta version) and (the main version -having SSL). I am getting the below issue.

> SMTPServerDisconnected at /accounts/signup/
>
> Connection unexpectedly closed
>
> Request Method:POSTRequest
> URL:http://beta-uralholidays.com/accounts/signup/Django
> Version:3.2.20Exception Type:SMTPServerDisconnectedException
> Value:Connection unexpectedly closedException
> Location:/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py, line 405, in getreplyPython
> Executable:/usr/bin/python3Python Version:3.10.12Python
> Path:['/home/booking_app-beta-20230928-130136/booking_app/booking_app',
> '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10',
> '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
> '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']Server time:Thu, 28 Sep 2023
> 14:05:55 +0000

I am trying to make it work in both my local server the production beta version (not having SSL) and the production main version (having SSL). Please suggest to me the exact changes I need to do. The hosting web server is digital ocean